# how to hide value of input element if its $pristine

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, input, angularjs-forms

I have ng-model attached to , but i want to display a default placeholder value if it's not been touched (`$pristine`). Is there any good way to do it? I cannot simply set my ng-model value to null during initial.
Here's my plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0kzKrwKTbJzsMGG8D1gQ?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="inputController">
    <input type="number" id="pricefield" min="0" name="price" placeholder="Price" ng-model="test.value" required/>

</body>

angular.module('plunker', []);
function inputController($scope) {
  $scope.test = {value: 0};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-attr` directive to set placeholder value dynamically, to check the form element is `pristine` or not you need to place this field inside a `form` & then you could easily check the `$pristine` property of that form element like `myForm.price.$pristine`.

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="number" id="pricefield" min="0" name="price" ng-model="test.value" 
   ng-attr-placeholder="{{myForm.price.$pristine ? 'Some Value': 'Default Value'}}" required/>
</form>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ij6lIVdHrljCnLy3WnGj?p=preview)

**Update**

I'd suggest to have one directive that will change hide the `$viewValue` on initial load & will show placeholder. Directive will have controller over the display value using `$formatters` on `ngModelControlller`

**Markup**

```
<input type="number" custom-dir id="pricefield" min="0" name="price" 
ng-attr-placeholder="{{myForm.price.$pristine ? 'Initial Placeholder': 'After change Placeholder'}}" 
ng-model="test.value" required/>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('hideInitialLoad', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      var initalHide = true;
      //format text going to user (model to view)
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        console.log(attr.min > value)
        if (initalHide){
          initalHide = false;
          return undefined;
        }
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7mHgpn0JpsM2DahFBco?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, @Pankaj Parkar, Thanks for this. however, i will need to set ng-model to 0 during initialization, and if i do that this will not quite work. (hide the initial value and display the placeholder)

Comment: @WABBIT0111 could you set `min="1"`..will work http://plnkr.co/edit/DzC5XyzXCmAGhTJgROCk?p=preview

Comment: @WABBIT0111 Glad to help you..Thanks :)